# Audio Recording and Playback in C : problem with audio gain

Tags: audio, freebsd, alsa

The question essentially is *how to correctly apply gain to an audio sample?*

I'm programming on FreeBSD and OSS, but manipulate volume in audio sample is probably the same for other OS and applications.

I'm studying others' applications internals like [ecasound](https://ecasound.seul.org/ecasound.git/) (in C++) and [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) (in C) but I don't know whats wrong when I read a sample and apply gain to it : it becomes distorted and noisy. **My point is to understand why it is not working to turn the volume down** (gain lesser than 1).

I'm working with stereo 16 bit LE samples. Without applying gain, it works perfectly (recording and playback).

I thought that I should convert an integer sample to float; multiply by a gain factor and restore it to integer. But it is not working. And it seems to be the exact same approach for [SoX in src/vol.c](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/ci/master/tree/src/vol.c) in function `static int flow`.

Below is my code (no additional libs used). The function playback is where I'm applying gain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "/usr/include/sys/soundcard.h"
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> //man 2 chmod
#include <signal.h>

#define DEBUG 1
#define log(msg) if (DEBUG) printf("[LOG] %s\n",msg)
#define err(msg)  {printf("[ERR] %s\n",msg); exit(1); }


const char *device = "/dev/dsp3.1";     //Audio device
char *rawFile = "/tmp/raw-file.wav";    //Raw file to record and playback
int fragmentSize = 256;
int b_continue = 1;


void signalHandler(int sigNum){
    log("Signal captured");
    b_continue = 0;
}


void configDevice(int fdDsp){
    int ossCapabilities = 0;

    if(fdDsp == -1)
        err("can't open device");

    if( ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_GETCAPS, &ossCapabilities) == -1)
        err("unsupported: SNDCTL_DSP_GETCAPS");

    /*
     * http://www.opensound.com/pguide/audio2.html
     */

    if(ossCapabilities & DSP_CAP_TRIGGER != DSP_CAP_TRIGGER){
        err("Triggering of recording/playback is not possible with this OSS device.");

    }

    if(ossCapabilities & DSP_CAP_REALTIME != DSP_CAP_REALTIME){
        err("No DSP_CAP_REALTIME.");

    }

    if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SETDUPLEX, &ossCapabilities) == -1)
        err("can't SNDCTL_DSP_SETDUPLEX");

    if(ossCapabilities & DSP_CAP_DUPLEX != DSP_CAP_DUPLEX)
        err("can't DSP_CAP_DUPLEX");

    int format = AFMT_S16_LE;   //set format
    if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SETFMT, &format ) == -1){
        err("Error setting format.");

    }

    int channels = 1; //mono=0 stereo=1
    if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_STEREO, &channels ) == -1){
        err("Error setting channels." );

    }
    // FREQUENCY RATE
    int speed = 44100;
    if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SPEED, &speed ) == -1){
        err("Error setting speed.");

    }

    // FRAGMENT SIZE
    if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SETBLKSIZE, &fragmentSize) == -1){ //normalmente 2048 bits
        err("Cannot SNDCTL_DSP_SETBLKSIZE.");

    }


}

void record(){
    int fdDsp = open(device, O_RDONLY);
    configDevice(fdDsp);
    //create file for writing
    const int fdOutput = open(rawFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR);

    if(fdOutput ==-1)
        err("can't open file to write");
    log("Recording...");

    do{
         // Triggers recording
         int enableBits = PCM_ENABLE_INPUT;
         if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SETTRIGGER, &enableBits) == -1)
             err("Can't record: SNDCTL_DSP_SETTRIGGER");

         int *buf[fragmentSize];
         read(fdDsp, buf, fragmentSize);
         write(fdOutput, buf, fragmentSize);

     } while(b_continue == 1);

     close(fdOutput);
     close(fdDsp);
}

void playback(){
    log("Opening file:");
    log(rawFile);
    log("On device:");
    log(device);

    int fdDsp = open(device, O_WRONLY);
    configDevice(fdDsp);

    const int fdInput = open(rawFile, O_RDONLY);

    if(fdInput ==-1)
        err("can't open file");
    log("Playing...");

    int eof = 0;

    do{
        // TRIGGERs PLAYBACK
        int enableBits = PCM_ENABLE_OUTPUT;
        if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SETTRIGGER, &enableBits) == -1){
            err("Cannot SNDCTL_DSP_SETTRIGGER.");

        }

        int buf[fragmentSize];
        eof = read(fdInput, buf, fragmentSize); //bytes read or -1 if EOF

        // audio processing:
        for(int i=0;i<fragmentSize;i++){
            // learning how to get left and right channels from buffer
            int l = (buf)[i] & 0xffff;
            int r = ((buf)[i] >> 16)  & 0xffff ;

            // FIXME: it is causing distortion:
            float fl = l;
            float fr = r;
            fl *= 1.0;
            fr *= 0.3; //if different than 1, sounds distorted and noisy
            l = fl;
            r = fr;


            // OK: unite Left and Right channels again
            int lr = (l ) | (r << 16);
            // OK: other options to mix these two channels:
            int lleft = l;              //Just the left channel
            int rright = (r << 16);     //Just the right channel
            int lmono = (l << 16) | l;  //Left ch. on both channels
            int rmono = (r << 16) | r;  //Right ch. on both channels

            // the output:
            (buf)[i] = lr;

        }

        write(fdDsp, buf, fragmentSize);
        if(b_continue == 0) break;
    } while(eof > 0);

    close(fdInput);
    close(fdDsp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    log("Ctrl^C to stop recording/playback");
    record();
    b_continue = 1; playback();
    log("Stopped.");
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out by [CL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11654/cl), I was using the wrong type and the last parameter of read()/write() is greater than the size of the buffer.

So, in FreeBSD I changed the buffer type to int16_t (short) defined in `#include <stdint.h>` .

Now I can correctly apply a gain as desired:

```
        float fl = l;
        float fr = r;
        fl *= 1.0f;
        fr *= 1.5f;
        l = fl;
        r = fr;
```

I'll accept [CL's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11654/cl) answer.

Now the audio processing loop is working with one sample per time (left and right interleaved).

**Updated code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "/usr/include/sys/soundcard.h"
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> //man 2 chmod
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdint.h> //has type int16_t (short)

#define DEBUG 1
#define log(msg) if (DEBUG) printf("[LOG] %s\n",msg)
#define err(msg)  {printf("[ERR] %s\n",msg); exit(1); }


const char *device = "/dev/dsp3.1";     //Audio device
char *rawFile = "/tmp/stereo.wav";    //Raw file to record and playback
int fragmentSize = 256;
int b_continue = 1;


void signalHandler(int sigNum){
    log("Signal captured");
    b_continue = 0;
}


void configDevice(int fdDsp){
    int ossCapabilities = 0;

    if(fdDsp == -1)
        err("can't open device");

    if( ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_GETCAPS, &ossCapabilities) == -1)
        err("unsupported: SNDCTL_DSP_GETCAPS");

    /*
     * http://www.opensound.com/pguide/audio2.html
     */

    if(ossCapabilities & DSP_CAP_TRIGGER != DSP_CAP_TRIGGER){
        err("Triggering of recording/playback is not possible with this OSS device.");

    }

    if(ossCapabilities & DSP_CAP_REALTIME != DSP_CAP_REALTIME){
        err("No DSP_CAP_REALTIME.");

    }

    if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SETDUPLEX, &ossCapabilities) == -1)
        err("can't SNDCTL_DSP_SETDUPLEX");

    if(ossCapabilities & DSP_CAP_DUPLEX != DSP_CAP_DUPLEX)
        err("can't DSP_CAP_DUPLEX");

    int format = AFMT_S16_LE;   //set format
    if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SETFMT, &format ) == -1){
        err("Error setting format.");

    }

    int channels = 1; //mono=0 stereo=1
    if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_STEREO, &channels ) == -1){
        err("Error setting channels." );

    }
    // FREQUENCY RATE
    int speed = 44100;
    if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SPEED, &speed ) == -1){
        err("Error setting speed.");

    }

    // FRAGMENT SIZE
    if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SETBLKSIZE, &fragmentSize) == -1){ //normalmente 2048 bits
        err("Cannot SNDCTL_DSP_SETBLKSIZE.");

    }


}

void record(){
    int fdDsp = open(device, O_RDONLY);
    configDevice(fdDsp);
    //create file for writing
    const int fdOutput = open(rawFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR);

    if(fdOutput ==-1)
        err("can't open file to write");
    log("Recording...");

    do{
         // Triggers recording
         int enableBits = PCM_ENABLE_INPUT;
         if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SETTRIGGER, &enableBits) == -1)
             err("Can't record: SNDCTL_DSP_SETTRIGGER");

         // Wrong:
//         int *buf[fragmentSize];
//         read(fdDsp, buf, fragmentSize);
//         write(fdOutput, buf, fragmentSize);
         int16_t *buf[fragmentSize/sizeof (int16_t)];
         read(fdDsp, buf, fragmentSize/sizeof (int16_t));
         write(fdOutput, buf, fragmentSize/sizeof (int16_t));

     } while(b_continue == 1);

     close(fdOutput);
     close(fdDsp);
}

void playback(){
    log("Opening file:");
    log(rawFile);
    log("On device:");
    log(device);

    int fdDsp = open(device, O_WRONLY);
    configDevice(fdDsp);

    const int fdInput = open(rawFile, O_RDONLY);

    if(fdInput ==-1)
        err("can't open file");
    log("Playing...");

    int eof = 0;

    do{
        // TRIGGERs PLAYBACK
        int enableBits = PCM_ENABLE_OUTPUT;
        if(ioctl(fdDsp, SNDCTL_DSP_SETTRIGGER, &enableBits) == -1){
            err("Cannot SNDCTL_DSP_SETTRIGGER.");

        }

        //Wrong buffer type (too large) and wrong last parameter for read():
//        int buf[fragmentSize];
//        eof = read(fdInput, buf, fragmentSize);
        int16_t buf[fragmentSize/sizeof (int16_t)];
        eof = read(fdInput, buf, fragmentSize/sizeof (int16_t));

        // audio processing:
        for(int i=0;i<fragmentSize/sizeof (int16_t);i++){
            int16_t l = buf[i];
            int16_t r = buf[i+1];

            // Using int16_t (short) buffer, gain works but stereo is inverted with factor >= 1.4f
            float fl = l;
            float fr = r;
            fl *= 2.0f;
            fr *= 3.0f;
            l = fl;
            r = fr;

            // the output:
            (buf)[i] = l;
            i++;
            (buf)[i] = r;

        }

//        write(fdDsp, buf, fragmentSize); //wrong
        write(fdDsp, buf, fragmentSize/sizeof (int16_t));
        if(b_continue == 0) break;
    } while(eof > 0);

    close(fdInput);
    close(fdDsp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    log("Ctrl^C to stop recording/playback");
    record();
    b_continue = 1; playback();
    log("Stopped.");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter of read()/write() is the number of bytes, but an entry in buf[] has more than one byte.

In the two's complement representation of binary numbers, negative values are (or must be) sign extended, i.e., the most significant bits are ones. In this code, neither extracting L/R channels nor combining them works correctly for negative samples.

The easiest way of handling negative samples would be to use one array entry per sample, i.e., `short int`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that tomorrow before mark solved